# Sobre espacios en IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

Pregunta me imagino un poco tonta, pero la verdad no se como arreglarla jaja.
Basicamente aveces cuando llevo en un codigo un rato se bugea o le pico a algo sin querer en el cual los espacios que hago, eliminan la letra sobre la casilla que estoy, osea no puedo separar el codigo con espacios, tengo que escribirlo nuevamente en esa linea.
Me pasa en Pycharm y en proteus

Me imagino que es algo muy basico pero ni idea que sea jaja

Comment: Porque no podes screenshots mejor?? No entiendo bien que te pasa... Creo que es por la tecla 'Insert' la que habilita algo así, pero no estoy seguro

Comment: @AlfaRojo Es que pues en screenshot no se ve nada jajaja, Solo se ve el codigo nada se ve diferente, Pero hmm de alguna digamos que las lineas de codigo no se mueven, Solo escribo encima de ellas. Al escribir encima de ellas se borra lo que estaba en ella. Digamos si tengo un "Hello world" Me pociono en la w y preciono espacio queda como "Hello orld" En vez de quedar como "hello w orld"

Comment: Casi seguramente no te das cuenta y pulsas la tecla "Insert", con lo cual el editor para de modo *insert* a modo *replace*.

Answer (score 2):

Es una función llamada `overtype` ([mas documentacion aqui](https://uniqcode.com/typewriter/)) que, como indicas, remplaza el caracter que tiene encima por el nuevo, allí el *over-type*. Principalmente lo usan aquellos que tienen buen manejo del teclado sin usar el mouse, algo muy conveniente para el desarrollador. Busca en tu teclado la tecla que diga `Ins` o también `Insert` está puede estar ubicada en diferentes lados, en mi caso la tengo en el 0 de mi num-pad y también tengo una encima del Delete. Busca en tu teclado una de esas teclas, presionala y comprueba, si no funciona, prueba con las teclas [Fn] + [Ins]

Comment: Muchas gracias, Si es eso. :)))))

Comment: @Pepee Te agradeceria si marcas como respuesta a tu pregunta, para que otra gente, si encuentra tu pregunta, sepa que eso te ayudó y posiblemente a ellos también